# ClassNotFoundException using Selenium Standalone Server

Tags: selenium, grails

I have a grails/groovy project that has one feature that uses selenium standalone server to do some test automation.

I keep getting this error running my grails project in production mode. If I run it directly from IntelliJ it works perfectly so I'm not sure what exactly is wrong.

Here is the relevant code:

```
 WebDriver driver
 DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome()
 capability.setBrowserName("chrome")
 capability.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS)
 driver = new RemoteWebDriver( new URL("http://192.168.83.124:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException error on the last line.

In my libraries for the project I'm using selenium-java-2.53.0.jar, selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar and sources has selenium-java-2.53.0-srcs.jar

I have absolutely no idea what's wrong and I've searched the internet exhaustively to  find a solution but have found nothing. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the full text of the error:

```
 2017-12-08 15:59:56,381 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR 
 errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - ClassNotFoundException occurred when processing request: [GET] /Diversotron-0.1/api/edit
 com.google.common.base.Function. Stacktrace follows:
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2585)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1906)
    at 
 org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)
    at diversotron.PropotronService.setPropotron(PropotronService.groovy:25)
    at diversotron.ApiController.edit(ApiController.groovy:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you add the actual exception to your question?

Comment: Tim, I added the full error above. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Selenium isn't declared in my BuildConfig.groovy file. That's why it ran via IntelliJ but not in production. Doing a grails prod war will not include the libraries. They have to be specified in the buildconfoig.groovy file.

I had to add these lines.

```
 def seleniumVersion = "2.53.0"
```

and in dependencies I had to add this:

```
 runtime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion"
```

Hopefully this will help someone else down the line!

Answer (score -1):

Map chrome Options = new Map();

ChromeOptions.put("binary","/use/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);

Web Driver driver = new Chrome Driver(capabilities);
try this